# VS2022 c# adds private modifier on file save

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, community-toolkit-mvvm

I want to use Microsoft MVVM Toolkit [ObservableProperty] attribute, it works fine, but in one case I need to use changed method:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private string? name;

partial void OnNameChanging(string? value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name is about to change to {value}");
}

partial void OnNameChanged(string? value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name has changed to {value}");
}
```

But I can't because VS2022 (v17.4.4) always is adding private modifier on this method when file is saving, which cause error:

> Note
> The generated methods are partial methods with no implementation, meaning that if you choose to implement them, you cannot specify an explicit accessibility for them. That is, implementations of these methods should also be declared as just partial methods, and they will always implicitly have private accessibility. Trying to add an explicit accessibility (eg. adding public or private) will result in an error, as that is not allowed in C#.

Adding any modifier (private, internal, public) causing the same error. also removing partial causing error as well.
How to force VS2022 to not add private modifier to methods on file save? Or how to remove this error?

Comment: Having the same issue with the same build of VS2022 using EF Core Database First approach and scaffolding my DB. Works fine until I need to set a base class as IdentityDbContext instead of just DbContext. If I find a solution to mine I'll share to see if it resolves yours as well.

Comment: I should have waited before posting last comment, my apologies. If you close your solution and make your edit in an external text-editor then save the file it will persist the changes when you reopen your solution. This will be the case until VS thinks the file is edited. After that point you're back to the beginning of VS auto adding the access modifier causing the error. This is a rough work around but it's what I'll be using until I find a more long-term solution.

Comment: @mpoust - it's nice workaround, thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have a code clean up extension loaded (CodeMaid in my instance) you can stop this from happening by amending the config for it.

In CodeMaid example it was modifying my events in global.asax.cs

Open the CodeMaid settings

[image: CodeMaid Settings]

Comment: I can confirm, that it wasn't VS2022 thing only CodeMaid which adds modifier during cleaning.